# Formula of rotating matrix/image 90 degree C++

Tags: c++, image, matrix

Let's say I have image, which I need to rotate 90 degrees in any direction and I just can't understand how to do that clear. I need to work with matrix, where Width - it's X, and Height - it's Y. I've already done rotating an image 180 degrees, but can't figure out 90 degrees.

Here are the examples. Let's say I have an image 3x4 pixels. Width = 3, Height = 4, the amount of data in each cell - `N = Width * Height = 3 * 4 = 12`. Let's make the matrix:

[image: Here it is]

The formula to easily go through the matrix is `y*Width + x`. And the formula for our rotating 180 degrees is:

```
N - Width + x - y * Width
```

So we have:

```
DataOut [y * Width + x] = DataIn [N - Width + x - y * Width]
```

Using this formula we get:

[image: this matrix]

But I can't come up with the formula of rotating 90 degrees. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You'll need matrix multiplications for this, e.g. the 90 degree rotational matrix is `[[0, -1], [1, 0]]` and the 180 degree matrix is `[[-1, 0], [0, -1]]`. Multiply each point with the matrix to get the point's rotated location. For any angle `a`, the rotational matrix is `[[cos(a), -sin(a)], [sin(a), cos(a)]]`.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply rotate the matrix by this:

```
for(int i=0; i<cols; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=rows; j++)
    {
        datOut[i][j]= datIn[rows-j][i];
    }
}
```

and in 1-D array:

```
for(int i=0; i<cols; i++)
{
    for(int j=1; j<=rows; j++)
    {
        datOut[i * rows + j]= datIn[(rows-j) * cols + i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the (x + y * width) to a simpler (x, y) representation.

```
using P = point_data_type;
P point(int x, int y){
   return DataIn[x + y * width];  // N - ...?
}
```

Now a right angle rotation is just a coordinate switch and maybe a sign correction.

```
P rotate90(int x, int y){
    return point(y, x);
}
```

This is a positive rotation in a left-handed system. 
Subtract x from Width if the rotation is in the wrong direction.